# Empty data after using UseEffect ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get news but i have an empty dictionary in the first render.
My useEffect

```
const [news, setNews] = useState({});
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [user, setUser] = useState({});

useEffect(() =>{
    const getNews = async() =>{
        const newsData = await httpClient.get(`/feed/${pk}/?page=${page.toString()}`)
        setNews(newsData.data);
        const userData = await httpClient.get('/profile/')
        setUser(userData)
    }
    getNews();
}, [page])
```

How can i get data in the first time render?

Comment: Why do you mean by "in first render"? At first there will be no data due to async operations take some time to load data. So empty on first render, useEffect executes get requests, state changed with new News and User, next render is called, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

because you have `[page]` in the dependency array - add hook for initial render:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => setPage(1), [])
```

Comment: But i need rerender when page param change

Comment: ok, I've changed the original answer

Comment: It doesn't work for me because i handle page number and rerender my info its for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have your state what you initialize it as on first render, react won't wait until useEffect is finished before render since that would lock up the UI.

You need some sort of loading indicator while data is fetching, you can do this for example

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [news, setNews] = useState({});
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [user, setUser] = useState({});

useEffect(() =>{
    const getNews = async() =>{
        const newsData = await httpClient.get(`/feed/${pk}/?page=${page.toString()}`)
        setNews(newsData.data);
        const userData = await httpClient.get('/profile/')
        setUser(userData)
        setLoading(false)
    }
    setLoading(true)
    getNews();
}, [page])

if (loading) {
  return <>{"loading"}</>
}
```

change the return value to whatever you want, maybe you want to just return an empty `<></>` component so that when it first shows up it'll have all the data.

Comment: It doesn't solve his problem of loading news on app first render. He needs something to trigger news loading on initial render and that would be a page change within another useEffect with empty dependency array

Comment: The `useEffect` should run either way when component mounts... I don't think the problem is that the `useEffect` isn't being run, that would be a React bug.

Comment: yep, you're right about dependent useEffect run at least once on component mount.